# What is the difference between cv2.warpPerspective and cv2.PerspectiveTransform?

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

According to [their](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) [description](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad327659ac03e5fd6894b90025e6900a7), both of them takes the matrix of transformation and apply it to the images. Can you please explain the difference? In which cases should I use one or another?

Comment: PerspectiveTransform works on vectors. warpPerspective works on images.

Comment: Homography is the matrix that can be used to transform point positions (rotation, translation, etc.) and if you dont want to do this with manual matrix-vector multiplication and dehomogenization you can use the function perspectiveTransform. If you want to perform this for every pixel position of an image and use interpolation etc. to get a new image, you can use warpPerspective